# Onenote share a page feature stopped working in onenote app version

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I store my onenote notebooks in a folder on onedrive. I make extensive use of the Share a page feature in onenote. Share a page works by clicking on the share button in the upper right, setting the link to read only, then copying the created link onto my blog or class management websites. Clicking on the link allows anyone to read that page of my notebook.

Now, clicking on the share button brings up an option to let me create an email invitation to share the entire notebook. Not what I want or am used to.

I am using Windows 10, the universal app version of onenote, and I believe that I have the commercial version of a windows license. I did recently add another computer to my license - a Microsoft Surface which I use occasionally. Share on the Microsoft Surface works correctly, generating a URL and allowing me to copy the URL to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

This, from Microsoft:

The previous single-page sharing implementation from personal OneDrive notebooks was our initial attempt to begin building out the larger feature set. However, this first step didn’t satisfy the needs of our customers and, compared to full notebook sharing, usage of the limited page sharing feature was very low. The technical path we need to take to build out the full OneNote page sharing experience requires us to deprecate the previous functionality until comprehensive work on these feature improvements can be completed.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-a-page-of-notes-or-an-entire-notebook-from-onenote-for-windows-10-d4a74a14-44a3-411e-8fb5-06e73ddf047f